# How to change size of an item in slider menu?

Tags: android

I'm new with android development and I wanted to know how to change the icon and text size of items in the slider menu.

I was wondering if I have to manually change every icon and text or if there is an alternative that will preset all the objects to a certain size (there probably is, I'm just a noob).

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_second_layout"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_order"
        android:title="Order" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_first_layout"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_user"
        android:title="User" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_third_layout"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_lookbook"
        android:title="Look Book" />

</group>
```

Comment: by "slider menu" you mean Navigation Drawer ?

Comment: Yea sorry forgot to say

Comment: Maybe you can find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31204320/how-can-i-change-the-navigationviews-item-text-size