# Reset selection in BottomNavigationView when navigate to the fragment

Tags: java, android, material-design

Currently in my app i have BottomNavigationView, that consists for example from 3 menu items, that linked with fragments:

1. Profile Fragment
2. Reader Fragment
3. Bookmarks Fragment

Also i have another fragments (Settings, Edit Profile, etc)

So when i navigate to the fragment that doesn't appear in BottomNavigationView menu i want to reset selection of menu item in BottomNavigationView.

In my code i only have NavController and this method

```
@Override
public void onFragmentNavigation(int id) {
    navController.navigate(id);
}
```

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/41372325/4961662