# Bottom Navigation View menu item title size

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

Good Morning,

i am using bottom navigation view to do my bottom menu.

and now the title is too big and i can't found any solution to solve it

[image]

Comment: check text size

Comment: you can customize font plz check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40172219/custom-textsize-of-bottomnavigationview-support-android

Answer (score 35):

1. Open values\dimens.xml
2. add this code

   ```
   <dimen 
         name="design_bottom_navigation_text_size"   
         tools:override="true">11sp </dimen>

   <dimen 
         name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size" 
         tools:override="true">12sp </dimen>
   ```

Answer (score 6):

```
 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/bg_grey"
      app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Active"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationView"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_color"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="BottomNavigationView" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption">
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
</style>

<style name="BottomNavigationView.Active" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption">
    <item name="android:textSize">11sp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Create new style

```
<style name="NavigationViewOwnStyle">
 <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">40dp</item><!-item height-->
 <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item> <!--item text size-->
</style>
```

and apply

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    ...
    ...
    app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavigationViewOwnStyle"
    ...
    ...
 />
```