# How to change the size of text in Bottom navigation android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, menu, bottomnavigationview

I want to change the `textSize` in `bottomNavigationView`
But could not find any way to do that is there any way to change the `textSize` of menu item in `bottomNavigation`

Answer (score 0):

**Create following resource file in `res>values>dimens`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_text_size" tools:override="true">12sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size" tools:override="true">12sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

This will override the attributes of `BottomNavigationView`

You can also change the `textSize` in selected and unselected items

Duplicate [Custom TextSize of BottomNavigationView support android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40172219/custom-textsize-of-bottomnavigationview-support-android)