# Is it possible to remove bold styling from menu item in NavigationView?

Tags: android, android-menu, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

[image]

```
<menu>
    ...
    <group
        android:id="@+id/nav_group_footer"
        android:checkableBehavior="none">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_item_last_updated"
            android:title="Last updated: 2018-09-07 21:47" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

I can get a handle to it in code like this `mLastUpdatedView = mNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_item_last_updated);` but then I'm not sure how to edit its styling. I've searched around and saw some possible solutions that involve altering styles.xml but I think if I change stuff there the other menu items will also be changed. I only want to remove bold textstyle from the footer. Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31204320/how-can-i-change-the-navigationviews-item-text-size

Answer (score 0):

```
follow this way for achieving that:  
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main2_drawer" >


            <TextView

                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:text="Last updated: 2018-09-07 21:47"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>



    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>.
```