# Android. Titles inside menu items displayed within NavigationView are not centered vertically

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Ok, I've got this problem. Titles inside menu items that are displayed in the NavigationView are not centered vertically. 
[image]

Basically I've got DrawerLayout as a top level view. NavigationView is positioned inside DrawerLayout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemIconPadding="10dp"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Then I've got menu with items inside divided by groups. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:id="@+id/misc">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_change_account"
            android:icon="@drawable/v_change_account"
            android:title="Сменить Л/С"
         />
    </group>

    <group android:id="@+id/menu_main">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_news"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_library_books_48px_2x"
            android:title="НОВОСТИ" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_services"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_touch_app_48px2x"
            android:title="ЗАЯВКИ" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_counter"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_developer_board_48px_2x"
            android:title="ВНЕСТИ ПОКАЗАНИЯ СЧЕТЧИКОВ" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_my_orders"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_activity_48px2x"
            android:title="ИСТОРИЯ" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

I tried to apply theme to NavigationView with different item attributes like this:

```
<style name="NavigationViewPadding">
<item name="android:itemPadding">10dp</item>
<item name="android:listPreferredItemHeight">20dp</item>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
 ..........
android:theme="@style/NavigationViewPadding"
/>
```

And this is my initialization code inside onCreate()

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);    

View hView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
imgProfile = (ImageView) hView.findViewById(R.id.imgProfile2);
txtNameProfile = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.txtNameProfile);
```

Tried to set every item attribute to NavigationView, tried out literally all available attributes to items but nothing works. I would be very appreciative for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How can I change the NavigationView's item text size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31204320/how-can-i-change-the-navigationviews-item-text-size][1])

You can check in this link, how to modify the menu item of navigation drawer and write both option of gravity in style like

```
  <style name="NavigationDrawerStyle">
      <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
      <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
      <item name="layout_gravity">center</item>
      <item name="gravity">center_horizontal</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: The link you posted pushed me towards the wright answer. In my case only overriding design_navigation_menu_item.xml helped. Don't know why but setting styles didn't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

try this `app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"` in your navigationview tag

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:itemIconPadding="10dp"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"/>


   <style name="NavigationDrawerStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    </style>
```

and include this in style.xml

Comment: I guess gravity should be set to center_vertical. But it didn't work anyway.

Comment: ohh use listview for your custom tiles and menu items to be align vertically