# Navigation Drawer item text getting bold on click

Tags: java, android, navigation, navigation-drawer

I have navigation drawer and in navigation view when i clicked on any item my top 5 item text turned into bold. I tried to remove fragment call but still it's all turned into bold.It doesn't matter which item i click it always turned into top 5 items into bold.

[image]

```
public class Navigation_Drawer extends AppCompatActivity {

    
    Toolbar toolbar;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    //RelativeLayout mainScreen;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       

        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer);
        
        //Initialise Views
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.Navigation_parent);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nvView);

        setupToolbar();
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
        setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
        settingHeaderItems();
        drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();
        drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        


    }

   

    public void setupToolbar() {
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.Navigation_Drawer_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
        // NOTE: Make sure you pass in a valid toolbar reference.  ActionBarDrawToggle() does not require it
        // and will not render the hamburger icon without it.
        //return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,  R.string.drawer_close);
        return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
    }

    public void setFragmentTitle(String title) {
        setTitle(title);
    }


    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                        Navigation_Drawer.this.selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                        Log.d(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected: Menu Item = "+menuItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });

    }



    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        // Create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on nav item clicked
        Fragment fragment = null;

        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

            case 1:
                fragment = new EditProfile();
                break;
            case 2:
                Log.d(TAG, "Home Fragment Pressed ");
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, android.app.FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                ChangeFragment_ViewPager(0, false);
                // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView
                // Set action bar title
                setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
                // Close the navigation drawer
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                return;

            case 3:
                Log.d(TAG, "PPL Fragment Pressed ");
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, android.app.FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

                ChangeFragment_ViewPager(1, false);
                // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView

                // Set action bar title
                setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
                // Close the navigation drawer
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                return;

            case 4:
                Log.d(TAG, "4 Fragment Pressed ");
                fragment = new 4();
                break;

            case 5:
                Log.d(TAG, "5 Fragment Pressed ");
                fragment = new 5();
                break;

            case 6:
                Log.d(TAG, "6 Fragment Pressed ");
                //fragmentClass = PPL_main.class;
                
                String link = " ";
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, link);

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Invite Friends"));
                // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView
                // Set action bar title
                // Close the navigation drawer
                return;

            case 7:
                Log.d(TAG, "Interest Fragment Pressed ");
                fragment = new 7();
                break;

            case 8:
                Log.d(TAG, "Setting Fragment Pressed ");
                fragment = new 8();
                break;

            case 9:
                Log.d(TAG, "Help Fragment Pressed ");
                //fragmentClass = PPL_main.class;
                fragment = new 9();
                
                break;

            case R.id.signOut_Fragment:
                                
                return;
        }


        // Close the navigation drawer
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.parentFragment, fragment.getClass(),null);
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_anim, R.anim.exit_anim);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        
    }

    private void settingHeaderItems() {
        View HeaderLayout = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.navigation_header_image);
        //Main Screen Tabs With VIew Pager
        headerImage = HeaderLayout.findViewById(R.id.HeaderImageView);
        headerImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.Navigation_Main_Layout, new EditProfile());
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_anim, R.anim.exit_anim);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            }
        });
        headerUserImage = HeaderLayout.findViewById(R.id.Header);
        userName = HeaderLayout.findViewById(R.id.ViewText);
        userViews = HeaderLayout.findViewById(R.id.Views);
        if (App_Functions.coverPath.equals("Invalid Image")) {
            headerImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cam_icon);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Path Of Cover Photo " + App1);
            Glide.with(this).load(App2)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE).skipMemoryCache(true)
                    .into(headerImage);
            //  Glide.with(context).load(App_Functions.coverPath).apply(new RequestOptions().skipMemoryCache(true).onlyRetrieveFromCache(false).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)).into(holder.HeaderImage);
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(App2);

        userName.setText(Session.getU());
       
        Glide.with(this).load(App2)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE).skipMemoryCache(true)
                .into(headerUserImage);

    }
  

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

  
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

  
} // END OF NAVIGATION DRAWERS
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Navigation_parent">

    <!--The Main Layout For Content-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--Toolbar for actionbar   -->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/Navigation_Drawer_toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/Navigation_Main_Layout"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >



       

            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/Navigation_Drawer_ViewPager">

            
            </androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

 

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Facing the exact same issue. The textstyle of top 5 items is set to bold when I click on any item. Maybe it's a bug in the material library that we are using?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same prolem by applying style(`itemTextAppearance`) in `NavigationView`

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        ...
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/Style_TextView" // You have to add this line
        ...
/>
```

in `themes.xml` add below style

```
<style name="Style_TextView">
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31204320/how-can-i-change-the-navigationviews-item-text-size) shows how you can change the size of the text. You should be able to reset the font weight of the items by adding

```
<item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
```